# Non-Renewable subscription in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, subscription

I was using "Auto-Renewable subscription" and it was working perfect and i can verify its recipt and can check status that its active or not, but apple has rejected it and suggested to use "Non-Renewable subscription", main problem using it is that, i can not test its status when after subscription, it expire or user remove it from his apple account, "Auto-Renewable subscription" use to expire after few minute so it was easy to test.

Can any one suggest how to test this scenario

Comment: I'm not sure of the situation you are trying to test. Why did Apple suggest you use Non-Rewnable subscriptions? What kind of product are you providing?

Answer (score 1):

With Non-Renewable Subscriptions you need to manage it yourself, on your server.  Once you verify a receipt with Apple, the ball is in your court to calculate and maintain the expiration date. As an example, there's nothing stopping you from selling 1-month subscriptions but giving every one an extra week since you're calculating your own expiration date.  Also beware that now **you** have to sync the subscription across all their device. With ARS you could use `restoreCompletedTransactions` to extend a subscription to a person's new device.  But with NRS, Apple requires you to implement a user account system with username and password to allow a user to log in (to your server) and extend their subscription to a new device.

With NRS you have more power but you also have a lot more responsibility.